# How to draw a different gradient fill for negative values?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linear-gradients

How to get GRADIENT fill on both positive and negative area, and not just solid color ?

- Positive area GRADIENT should be blue
- Negative area GRADIENT should be red
- gradient color should be black/transparent near Y axis (value 0)

The goal:
https://codepen.io/francoisG/pen/gOOoEjQ

To achieve this goal, I had to hard code the second gradient stop:

- positive gradient: second stop forced to 0.67
- negative gradient: second stop forced to 0.33

Obviously, these 2 values should not be hard coded, so how can I calculate these 2 values in live, whatever the data?
Each value should be the percentage of the gradient portion, compared to the total range of the series.

- For positive gradient: (Ymax - 0) / (Ymax - Ymin), which is in this case 12 / 12 + 6 = 12/18 = 0.67
- For negative gradient: (0 - Ymin) / (Ymax - Ymin), which is in this
  case 6 / 12 + 6 = 6/18 = 0.33

My problem is that I don't know to calculate these data within the chart code. I tried many things with Ymin and Ymax, without success.
Thanks for your help

```
series: [{
  name: 'John',
  data: [3, 4, -6, 5, 4, 10, 12],
  fillColor: {
    linearGradient: {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
    stops: [
      [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
      [0.67, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
    ]
  },
  zones: [{
    value: 0,
    color: '#D76363',
    fillColor: {
      linearGradient: {x1: 0, y1: 1, x2: 0, y2: 0},
      stops: [
        [0, 'rgba(215,99,99,0.5)'],
        [0.33, 'rgba(2,0,0,0)']
      ],
    }
  }]
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is? When I check your pen it's perfectly blue on positive and red on negative all the way up / down to zero?

Comment: Thanks to help me. Yes,fill colors are correct, but I'd like them in LINEAR GRADIENT style. Gradient details are given in my first post. Any idea?

Comment: I edited my first post, with an example of the goal. Anyone has the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `chart.events.load` callback function and `update()` method to set those calculated values. Check demo and code posted below:

```
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  type: 'areaspline',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      const chart = this;
      const yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

      let posGrad = (yAxis.max - 0) / (yAxis.max - yAxis.min);
      let negGrad = (0 - yAxis.min) / (yAxis.max - yAxis.min);

      chart.series[0].update({
        fillColor: {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
          stops: [
            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
            [posGrad, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
          ]
        },
        zones: [{
          value: 0,
          color: '#D76363',
          fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 0,
              y1: 1,
              x2: 0,
              y2: 0
            },
            stops: [
              [0, 'rgba(215,99,99,0.5)'],
              [negGrad, 'rgba(2,0,0,0)']
            ],
          }
        }]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9wey1z4q/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: It works fine when running the chart the first time, but if I update data with something like   var newData = [12, 4, 10, 2, 4, 100, 12];  chartarea.series[0].setData(newData);  the gradients are not updated.

Comment: I've edited the demo. It can be achieved using `render` event instead of `load`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9wey1z4q/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fillColor` and `negativeFillColor` together and configure the for linear gradient style. I modified your code here: https://codepen.io/tredex/pen/yLLprxz

```
negativeFillColor: {
    linearGradient: {x1: 0, y1: 1, x2: 0, y2: 0},
    stops: [
      [0, '#D76363'],
      [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
    ]
},

fillColor: {
  linearGradient: {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
  stops: [
    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please move relevant code from Codepen to SO so it can be archived.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That's where I went too. But I don't see the positive and negative gradients going to very dark (transparent) at X axis (y=0). The problem of this code is that the gradients are computed for the whole shape. Positive gradient should start from 0 to Ymax value. And negative gradient should start from 0 to Ymin value

Comment: For the negative gradient, I think we should replace the 1 from the second stop by the percentage (0 - Ymin) / (Ymax - Ymin), eg 0.4, and do the same for the positive gradient. But I don't know how to calculate this... Please help

Comment: I edited my first post, with an example of the goal. Anyone has the solution?

Comment: Can you define data before creating your chart? for example define `var mData=[3, 4, -6, 5, 4, 10, 12]` at the beginning then defining data like `data: mData`. If that is the case then you can calculate min and max of the data array first and then use it instead of hard-coded parts